# Custom action rendering fails on production server, but worked on staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason the rendering of a view is failing on the production server, however has worked fine on the local dev and staging server.

In the app different accounts can have custom layouts and home page or use the default.

Snippet from production server (where it is failing)

```
Rendering template within layouts/accounts/default/layout
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing layout main/../layouts/accounts/default/home in view path app/views):
```

Snippet from local dev server (where it is working)

```
Rendering template within layouts/accounts/default/layout
Rendering main/../layouts/accounts/default/home
```

The folder structure is like so

```
app
|- views
|  `- main
|     `- some_other_main_templates
`- layouts
   `- accounts
      |- default
      |  |- layout
      |  `- home
      `- some_other_account
```

Here is a snippet of the code from within the index action of the MainController

```
layout_location = @account.use_custom_design? ? @account.subdomain : "default"
render :action => "../layouts/accounts/#{layout_location}/home", 
       :layout => "accounts/#{layout_location}/layout"
```

The files are checked in and on the server (As mentioned these problems were not seen on the staging server, so the source control isn't the issue).

Does anyone have any ideas?

FYI: I can split up the custom home and layout files into separate dirs, but I would like to keep them together to keep things organized.

Comment: Is there some reason why you're trying to pass that unruly relative path off as an "action?"

Comment: Is there a better way to render the template of choice?

Comment: Maybe that would be render :template => ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use render :template => ...